# Merge 2 event actions when displaying a report

Tags: google-analytics

In an event report, is it possible to merge 2 event actions to show as just one? For example, in the below image, I'm trying to display those 2 event action rows `inline` and `free-trial` as one row `free-trial`.

[image]

What method can I use to achieve this? I've gone to 'Edit' on the report, do I then create a filter? In my filters I don't have the option to combine only include and exclude though?

Comment: Can you just re-tag the events on your site so that they use the same name?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options really. I would just go for the total row after applying filters. If that view is all you need.
But many ways of do it:

1. Retag as Stephen indicated
2. Make a view filter that would change one action into another
3. Leverage custom reporting, use filters there, but then don't pull the action, grouping this data by a different dimension. That would glue them into one line.
4. What else? ETL the data into BQ or a different destination and do whatever you want with it? Note that google sheets and Excel are destinations too, there are simple free extensions that allow for it.